# Are there other management app-modules in Django?

Tags: django

A typical app looks like this:

```
myapp/
├── forms.py
├── __init__.py
├── management
│   ├── commands
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── my_command.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── models.py
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
└── views.py
```

`.management.commands` is the Django-enforced standard for management commands but why is it so deep. Are there other kinds of `.management` module?

Answer (score 0):

This is just how Django detects custom management commands. Check the [source code for get_commands() here.](https://github.com/django/django/blob/a6baada7bdf0c2b14045ee86364f9401c7b91b7c/django/core/management/__init__.py#L45)

> Returns a dictionary mapping command names to their callback applications.
>       This works by looking for a management.commands package in django.core, and
>       in each installed application -- if a commands package exists, all commands
>       in that package are registered.
>       Core commands are always included. If a settings module has been
>       specified, user-defined commands will also be included.